# How to add a key binding to maximize/close all windows?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, openbox, lxde, window-management

Lubuntu uses LXDE with Openbox. I can configure key bindings in `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml`

I want to add key bindings to maximize all windows and have the current active one on top.

I also need to have a key binding to close all windows.

**Example**

```
<keybind key="KP_Prior">
  <action name="Execute">
    <startupnotify>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
      <name>File manager</name>
    </startupnotify>
    <command>lxsession-default file_manager</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

Comment: To use the new keybindings I use `openbox --reconfigure`

Answer (score 2):

This [link](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Bindings) might be helpful for you. I can't found what you want exactly but this snippet can toggle maximize a window:

```
<keybind key="A-Return">
<action name="ToggleMaximize"/>
</keybind>
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I used Ctrl+f in browser to find in website and there is no such thing.